# Load training data sequentially to avoid memory error

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

How can I load data of shape:

```
X_train : (4864,6989)
X_test : (2085, 6989)
y_train : (4864, 270)
y_test : (2005, 270)
```

into the memory? I have 16 GB of RAM.

**What I have tried:**

1. Loading data in chunks

   `extracted_df = pd.read_csv("ExtractedData.csv", chunksize=6953)`
2. Using virtual memory (paging) by going in the system settings
3. Reducing the chunk size.

I am able to fit the data on a relatively simple model. However for the model I have defined, I can't seem to get out of the memory error.

```
def build_model(embed_size, max_length, vocab_size):
    def build_model():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, input_length=max_length))
        model.add(Conv1D(embed_size, 7, activation='tanh', padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
        model.add(Conv1D(embed_size, 7, activation='tanh', padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
        model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(150, activation="tanh"))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(150, activation="tanh"))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(output_nodes, activation="softmax"))
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
        plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
        return model

    return build_model

feature_nodes = X_train.shape[1]
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model(feature_nodes, feature_nodes, 1000), epochs=3, batch_size=16,
                                verbose=1, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(patience=3, monitor='accuracy')],
                                validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

I don't understand dask enough to try it but as I understand, it is for really huge data. My data has 98k rows and 2 columns. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at making a custom keras data generator to feed the data in batches to the model and then use to `.fit_generator` method to fit the model.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a skeleton code that you can provide?